# How to display comma separated images in DataList in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, datalist

i am developing asp.net c# application, in that i have a scenario, which is used to show comma seperated images in DataList like the below images names
in **image_url** field

tmp_IMG_20170522_0837451077517149.jpg,
tmp_IMG_20170522_083635-993558832.jpg,
tmp_IMG_20170522_083327-596532566.jpg,tmp_IMG_20170522_0839271082156791.jpg,
tmp_IMG_20170522_092501-744906076.jpg,
tmp_IMG_20170522_084036-2041074160.jpg,
tmp_IMG_20170522_091330-34718281.jpg,
tmp_IMG_20170522_092627-1388224780.jpg,
tmp_IMG_20170522_082648-859515701.jpg,tmp_IMG_20170522_083853-597136928.jpg

[image]

suppose if the field has only one images names means it will display in DataList,

but i don't know how to display comma seperated images in DataList,
please any one help need.

**Asp.Net :**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DLImages" RepeatColumns="2" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div id='gallery'>
        <a href='<%# Eval("image_url","../Uploads/App_Images/{0}")%>'>
          <img src='<%# Eval("image_url","../Uploads/App_Images/{0}") %>' width="200" height="200" />
        </a>
     </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**C# :**

```
private void FillDataList()
    {
        try
        {
            bolImages.ID=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
            DataSet dsImages = new DataSet();
            dsImages = bolImages.SelectImagesByID();

            if (dsImages.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DLImages.DataSource = dsImages;
                DLImages.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
        }
    }
```

**Query :**

```
public DataSet SelectImagesByID()
    {
        try
        {
         Squery = @"select image_url from BMTEST..Images WHERE ID='" + ID + "';
         return dal.DBRead(Squery);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**Example :**

it shows one images if image_url is as follows:

tmp_IMG_20170522_0837451077517149.jpg

[image]

but how to display multiple images if it is multiple comma seperated.

tmp_IMG_20170522_083327-596532566.jpg,tmp_IMG_20170522_0839271082156791.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (dsImages.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var filelists = dsImages.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image_url"].ToString().Split(',').ToList();
                List<string[]> imagelist = new List<string[]>();
                List<string[]> videolist = new List<string[]>();
                if (filelists.Count >= 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < filelists.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string FileName = filelists[i].ToString();
                        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);

                        if (Extension == ".jpg" || Extension == ".JPG" || Extension == ".jpeg" || Extension == ".JPEG" ||
                           Extension == ".gif" || Extension == ".GIF" || Extension == ".png" || Extension == ".PNG" ||
                           Extension == ".tiff" || Extension == ".TIFF" || Extension == ".bmp" || Extension == ".BMP")
                        {
                            imagelist.Add(new string[] { filelists[i].ToString() });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            videolist.Add(new string[] { filelists[i].ToString() });
                        }
                    }

                    DataTable dtImages = ConvertListToDataTable(imagelist);
                    DLImages.DataSource = dtImages;
                    DLImages.DataBind();

                    DataTable dtVideo = ConvertListToDataTable(videolist);
                    DLVideos.DataSource = dtVideo;
                    DLVideos.DataBind();

                }                    
            }
            else
            {

            }




static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string[]> list)
    {
        // New table.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        // Get max columns.
        int columns = 0;
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            if (array.Length > columns)
            {
                columns = array.Length;
            }
        }

        // Add columns.
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add();
        }

        // Add rows.
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(array);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try like this and let me know how it comes:

```
<div id='gallery'>
    <a href='<%# string.Format("../Uploads/App_Images/{0}", Eval("image_url"))%>'>
         <img src='<%# string.Format("../Uploads/App_Images/{0}", Eval("image_url"))%>' width="200" height="200" />
     </a>
</div>
```

As per the comment, it is clear that the row contains comma separated values and you need these values as the datasource instead for rows so what you have to do is change the DataSource like the following:

```
if (dsImages.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int rowNumber = 0;
    DLImages.DataSource = dsImages.Tables[0][rowNumber]["image_url"].Split(',').ToList();
    DLImages.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: image not shown @un-Lucky, it shows only blank which is shows like no image in image path.

Comment: @Surya: can you please inspect those elements and check whether the path are showing correctly? if not make necessary changes to point to the correct path

Comment: hi sir, i checked once again, image path is correct. but its always shown like previous error, if one image means it displayed, but multiple its not shown.   like this : https://68.media.tumblr.com/78b9eb663c155ba7f5ebdf91d4b8e705/tumblr_inline_noinhzuW4B1srto7p_250.png

Comment: @Surya: In the above mentioned case(error image) can you please inspect and share the value for `href`

Comment: <a href='../Uploads/App_Images/tmp_IMG-20170531-WA00022139041948.jpg,tmp_IMG-20151213-WA0000-115062032.jpg,tmp_IMG-20170531-WA0001897501569.jpg,tmp_PicsArt_05-31-07.35.08184268213.jpg'>
<img src='../Uploads/App_Images/tmp_IMG-20170531-WA00022139041948.jpg,tmp_IMG-20151213-WA0000-115062032.jpg,tmp_IMG-20170531-WA0001897501569.jpg,tmp_PicsArt_05-31-07.35.08184268213.jpg' width="200" height="200" />
 </a>

Comment: I suggest u take the entire set of images's names in a container, then loop it unless the ',' ends. Inside the looping hit the DB or the web service, & bind it. U can get concepts of code if u use oData or equivalent. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
        dsImages = bolImages.SelectImagesByID();

        if (dsImages.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            string[] values = dsImages.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
              values[i] = values[i].Trim();
            }
            var newdsImages = values.ToList();
            DLImages.DataSource = newdsImages ;
            DLImages.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split comma separated image paths before loading them to dataset

```
DLImages.DataSource = dsImages;
```

here dsImages should be something like

```
dsImages.Split[','];
```

Comment: hi @Znaneswar dsImages.Split[',']; is not accepted in dataset

Comment: I think in view code its possible because all the image paths are coming in href path
spiting  and looping the comma separated urls in view is better idea

Comment: hi @Znaneswar, i don't know how to implement which you told, if you have any code pls attach.